# How to sort a file, based on its numerical values for a field?

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, command

Example `file.txt`:

```
  100 foo
  2 bar
  300 tuu
```

When using `sort -k 1,1 file.txt`, the order of lines will not change, though we are expecting :

```
  2 bar
  100 foo
  300 tuu
```

How to sort a field consisting of numbers based on the absolute numerical value?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Take a peek at the [man page for sort](http://ss64.com/bash/sort.html)...

> ```
>    -n, --numeric-sort
>           compare according to string numerical value
> ```

So here is an example...

```
sort -n filename
```

Comment: Thank you all, folks! This is wired, because I looked over its man page back and forth several times and I didnt see that option. Ah, I was at a simplified man page. Damn!

Comment: Please note that, for floating points, using `-g, --general-numeric-sort` could be more advisable. This further allows scientific notation e.g. 1.234E10 etc.

Answer (score 136):

If you are sorting strings that are mixed text & numbers, for example filenames of rolling logs then sorting with `sort -n` doesn't work as expected:

```
$ ls |sort -n
output.log.1
output.log.10
output.log.11
output.log.12
output.log.13
output.log.14
output.log.15
output.log.16
output.log.17
output.log.18
output.log.19
output.log.2
output.log.20
output.log.3
output.log.4
output.log.5
output.log.6
output.log.7
output.log.8
output.log.9
```

In that case option `-V` does the trick:

```
$ ls |sort -V
output.log.1
output.log.2
output.log.3
output.log.4
output.log.5
output.log.6
output.log.7
output.log.8
output.log.9
output.log.10
output.log.11
output.log.12
output.log.13
output.log.14
output.log.15
output.log.16
output.log.17
output.log.18
output.log.19
output.log.20
```

from man page:

> ```
>    -V, --version-sort
>           natural sort of (version) numbers within text
> ```

Comment: This tripped me up, so thank you! The other thing that messed me up, at least on my cygwin, is that even when piping the `ls` through `sed` substitutions to remove the letters and leave only numbers, apparently the colored output was affecting things as well. So running `ls --color=never` also made a difference.

Comment: Awesome, `-V` is exactly what I was looking for. I should make a habit of looking through the man pages first.

Comment: Indeed, `-V` was the version I needed!

Answer (score 19):

Well, most other answers here refer to

```
sort -n
```

However, I'm not sure this works for negative numbers. Here are the results I get with sort version 6.10 on Fedora 9.

Input file:

```
-0.907928466796875
-0.61614990234375
1.135406494140625
0.48614501953125
-0.4140167236328125
```

Output:

```
-0.4140167236328125
0.48614501953125
-0.61614990234375
-0.907928466796875
1.135406494140625
```

Which is obviously not ordered by numeric value.

Then, I guess that a more precise answer would be to use `sort -n` but only if all the values are positive.

P.S.: Using `sort -g` returns just the same results for this example

Edit:

Looks like the locale settings affect how the minus sign affects the order ([see here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/linux-sort-702056/)). In order to get proper results I just did:

```
LC_ALL=C sort -n filename.txt
```

Answer (score 8):

You have to use the numeric sort option:

```
sort -n -k 1,1 File.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `sort -n` or `sort --numeric-sort`.

Answer (score 1):

You must do the following command:

`sort -n -k1 filename`

That should do it :)

Answer (score -1):

Use sort -nr for sorting in descending order. Refer

[Sort](http://ss64.com/bash/sort.html)

Refer the above Man page for further reference

Answer (score -4):

```
    echo " Enter any values to sorting: "
read n
i=0;
t=0;
echo " Enter the n value: "
for(( i=0;i<n;i++ ))
do
read s[$i]
done
for(( i=0;i<n;i++ ))
do
for(( j=i+1;j<n;j++ ))
do
if [ ${s[$i]} -gt ${s[$j]} ]
then
t=${s[$i]}
s[$i]=${s[$j]}
s[$j]=$t
fi
done
done
for(( i=0;i<n;i++ ))
do
echo " ${s[$i]}  "
done
```

Comment: Care to add in a bit of text explanation about what this code does?