# Using awk and sorting

Tags: linux, sorting, awk

I have a file that contains names and numbers like so:

students.txt:

```
Student A F 40 50 60
Student B F 50 60 70
Student C M 60 70 80
Student D M 100 90 90
Student E F 80 90 100
Student F M 20 30 40
Student G M 30 40 50
```

I want to sort these names using awk, and sort by the last number on a line.

When I try

```
sort -k6 students.txt | awk '{print}'
```

The output that is given to me is

```
... 100
... 40
... 50
... 60
... 70
... 80
... 90
```

As a result, it is mostly sorted except the first one. Is there a reason why 100 is at the start of the output rather than at the end?

Comment: There's no need for `| awk '{print}'` here.

Comment: You're right, my first attempt originally had `| awk '{print $1 " " $2}'` for clarity but it was my mistake to leave that there after getting rid of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting according to field's numerical value in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4856030/608639)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use numeric sort, via the `-n` flag. From the `sort(1)` [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html):

```
   -n, --numeric-sort
          compare according to string numerical value
```

Result:

```
$ sort -n -k6 students.txt
Student F M 20 30 40
Student G M 30 40 50
Student A F 40 50 60
Student B F 50 60 70
Student C M 60 70 80
Student D M 100 90 90
Student E F 80 90 100
```